# Как заблокировать кнопку?

Tags: html, php

Если данные с формы не введены, то кнопка отправить не работает.

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам решение на jquery

```
$(function() {
  $(":text").keypress(check_submit).each(function() {
    check_submit();
  });
});

function check_submit() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```